# Image and Checkbox Inside Label in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I have the following html:

```
<label>
    <img src="..." />
    <input type="checkbox" .../>
</label>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, clicking the `img` will check/uncheck the checkbox. But in IE8, it doesn't respond when the image is clicked.

Is my html tag invalid?

Answer (score 3):

IE8 is .. stupid?  Change the `<img>` to a `<span>` with `background-image` CSS for the same image.

Comment: I feel stupid using semantically incorrect `background-image` instead of `<img>` because of stupid browsers.

Comment: I'm not able to use `background` in CSS to get the image as the `img src` is dynamically obtained. Is there another workaround for this? I'm facing exactly the same scenario as the original question. Thanks.